# How do I generate an IOTA address from a given seed in Javascript without making an HTTP(s) requst?

Tags: iri-node, address, javascript

In all of the ways to [`getNewAddress()`](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js#getnewaddress) we have to call an iri node ([reference](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/develop/examples/multisig.js)).

But using the seed it is a deterministic algorith, why do I have to use and http request to do that?

How do I generate an IOTA address from a given seed in Javascript without making an HTTP(s) requst?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getNewAddress` can either search for an unused address (this will do HTTP requests to check if an address was already spent from or has a balance) or you can use it to get a list of addresses (you have to give the **total** number you want), which will work without any HTTP requests (but obviously you cannot know whether the addresses have already been spent).

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to infer that the reason why most functions are from the IOTA node instance is so it can refer to the network about all these things?

Like when I make a digest, I have to use `iota.multisig.getDigest` where `var iota = new IOTA({'provider': 'https://site.tld:443'})`?

Comment: @Tsangares Most functions require a node. But some do not, and the node is not contacted in that cases. Just pass an invalid node and you'll see if if it is required for the workflow you are trying (as you get Connection Refused).